# how to find a point in the path of a line

Tags: objective-c, ios, math

I've got two points between which im drawing a line (`x1,y1` and `x2,y2`) but i need to know the coordinates of `x3,y3` which is `gapSize` away from point `x2,y2`. Any ideas on how to solve this problem (the program is written in objective-c if that is helpful at all)?

[image: example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply calculate the angle in radians as

```
double rads = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
```

Then you get the coordinates as follows:

```
double x3 = x2 + gapSize * cos(rads);
double y3 = y2 + gapSize * sin(rads);
```

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the distance between P1 and P2: `d=sqrt( (y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)`

Then `x2 = (d*x1 + gapSize*x3) / (d+gapSize)`

So `x3 = (x2 * (d+gapSize) - d*x1) / gapSize`

Similarly, `y3 = (y2 * (d+gapSize) - d*y1) / gapSize`

Sorry for the math. I didn't try to code it but it sounds right. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Simplest (to me) is the following. I'll write it in terms of mathematics since I can't even spell C.

Thus, we wish to find the point C = {x3,y3}, given points A = {x1,y1} and B = {x2,y2}.

The distance between the points is

```
d = ||B-A|| = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

A unit vector that points along the line is given by

```
V = (B - A)/d = {(x2 - x1)/d, (y2-y1)/d}
```

A new point that lies a distance of gapSize away from B, in the direction of that unit vector is

```
C = B + V*gapSize = {x2 + gapSize*(x2 - x1)/d, y2 + gapSize*(y2 - y1)/d}
```